# Is animal sacrifice valid in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rituals, rig-veda, purva-mimamsa

Do shrutis and smritis validate animal sacrifices? Do Vedas validate animal sacrifices? Any sutras/dharmashastras/works of any great hindu sage validate it? Does mimamsa (purva mimamsa) validate it? Please help.

Comment: Animal sacrifice is chief in Tantra, less from Vedas. Vedas do have mentions of animal sacrifices and some smiritis do acknowledge it too. But certain smiritis restrict that.

Comment: @User29499
 I am not concerned with tantras, the question is that, do shrutis or smritis validate it? like there can be alternatives but is animal sacrifice permissible from the point of view of shrutis and smritis? The gist of the question demands a yes/no answer, if you have an answer then please provide references, that would help a lot, thank you

Comment: Do Shrutis validate that? In certain context, yes. Do smirtis? Yes. Are there any alternatives to animal sacrifice? There are various purposes of animal sacrifices, so that depends. [Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, Vishnu Purana, even Mahabharata like texts do acknowledge that]

Comment: @User29449
The gist of the question demands a yes or no answer from shrutis and smritis, if there is any. there maybe alternative methods provided in shastras but do they specifically put a nishedh on animal sacrifice? if you have an answer please answer with references,+I am not concerned with tantras, Thank you.

Comment: @User29449
please provide references. that would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: There are already very similar questions in the website if you search. So, I'd not write another new one. Thank You

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: @User29449 where Brihadaranyaka Upanishad support animal sacrifice?

Comment: @Hope Here: [Ashvamedha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117895.html#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20eulogy,tribute%20to%20the%20sacrifice.)

Comment: @User29449 I have checked all arya samaj translation in those ashvamedha have no reference of meat . Also, Yajur Veda 1.1 Abstract Meaning:  O human! Animals are Aghnya – NOT TO BE KILLED.  PROTECT THE ANIMALS. Vedas are word of God and how can word of God be contradictory. So, in my opinion all translation about horse meat are fake as there can be no contradic

Comment: Contradictory + fake are the claims. As arya samaj translates from nirukta

Comment: @Hope That's also the right interpretation of it. Arya Samaj has come up with another way to interpret that. But there are far-reaching consequences of their policy of interpreting that - it doesn't take account into Shiva/Vishnu like god, also nullifies avatarvaad, rejects puranas (which were the main source to validate such sacrifices).

Comment: @Hope My answer was from a more historical perspective. It is known that kings during the old era used to sacrifice horses in the Ashvamedha ritual. Additionally, the Upanishad clearly mentions sacrificing horses for Indra, and if someone interprets it as non-violent sacrifice (I don't know if there any any basis for that or not), it turns out to change the entire ritual of the thing.

Comment: @User29449 you have also told that vedant rejects avtarvaad. And if second statement about killing of horse is considered. Then words of God are contradictory in vedas. Because in 1 verse I tell you not to murder and in other I tell you murder for glory of God. It doesn't make sense

Comment: @Hope Some scholars believe words - *sacrifice* and *kill* are different and hence not contradictory in Vedas.

Comment: @User29449 can I know where is it sacrifice=kill is false. Any reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151526/discussion-between-user-29449-and-hope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the shastras certainly validate pashubali (animal sacrifice).

I know for sure that the Srimad Devi Bhagavatam goes in depth about how pashubali should be carried out. You can look into this yourself if you'd like.

The Brahma Sutras also validate pashubali. Veda Vyasa Himself says “If it be argued that rites (involving killing of animals) are unholy, we say, no, since they are sanctioned by scriptures." - Brahma Sutras 3.1.25

Adi Shankaracharya also supports the idea of pashubali being sanctioned by the shastras in His bhashya of the Brahma Sutras under the aforementioned verse.